# pre-processing for clustering of network data

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn, data-mining

I will apply clustering (k-means) to network data which has columns like ip address and port number. Despite port numbers are integer, for example relation between 80th and 81th ports are not closer than relation between 80th and 1800th. So I think I should not use them as they are (integers).

I think using DictVectorizer is not suitable too because there are 65535 ports so I need a different approach. IP addresses have same problem with ports.

Is there any way to resolve the problem with or without scikit-learn (or with or without k-means)?

Comment: what are the total number of data points? and how are the port|ip numbers distributed? almost uniformly or are some port|ip numbers very frequent and others sporadic?

Comment: There is not a certain dataset. It will be applied to several datasets but I can say that some port numbers will be abundant for example 80 while 60103 will not appear in most of the datasets. But I cannot say same thing for IP addresses. I couldnt understand your question about port/ip distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k-means must compute **means**.

What is the mean of ports 80 and 81? Port 80.5?

No, k-means is *only* sensible for *continuous* and *linear* attributes. Otherwise, neither variance (optimization criterion of k-means) nor the mean make any sense...

You can try various hacks, such as making each port a separate attribute. But k-means also does not make sense for binary data.

Use other algorithms. Distance-based algorithms are fine, *if* you have figured out how to measure similarity.

Comment: why k-means doesnt work with binary data(you mean DictVectorizer here i think)?

Comment: It will "work", but the results do not make much sense, as the "centers" will no longer be binary; and usually the results will be pretty crappy. Make sure to double-check any output.

Comment: "does not make sense for binary data": when combined with PCA/SVD, it can actually work quite nicely.